# How to get all the assets in a Collection in AEM?

Tags: java, aem, query-builder

I am trying to get all the assets inside a collection in AEM given the path of the collection.

Let's say the path of the collection is 
/content/dam/collections/public/-/-XZMzZlhkJKIa7-Mg15h/testing

I need to get all the assets inside this collection.

I checked under content/dam/collections the assets are not stored under this location

I even tried by writing a query in query builder in AEM giving type:dam:asset
and path:"location of the collection"

I couldn't get any results.

I just need to get all the assets under the collection in Java or QueryBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource Collection API will be used to retrieve the assets in a Collection.

Below code should work for you.

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver
            .getResource("/content/dam/collections/k/kXjI0j44sW4pq2mWc9fE/public collections");
    if (null != resource) {
        log.debug("resource path is {}", resource.getPath());
        ResourceCollection resourceCollection = resource.adaptTo(ResourceCollection.class);
        if (null != resourceCollection) {
            Iterator<Resource> resourceIterator = resourceCollection.getResources();
            while (resourceIterator.hasNext()) {
                Resource damResource = resourceIterator.next();
                log.debug("damResource path is {}", damResource.getPath());
                imagePaths.add(damResource.getPath());
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer below links for the model class and a sample Component

> https://github.com/sudheerdvn/aem-flash/blob/develop/core/src/main/java/com/flash/aem/core/models/ReadCollectionAssets.java
>
> https://github.com/sudheerdvn/aem-flash/tree/develop/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/aem-flash/components/content/read-collection-assets

Comment: Can I get the query to get all the paths of the assets in a collection  in Querbuilder given the path of the collection?

Comment: @acus - you don't even need a query - all the references are stored in a multi value field. See my answer.

Comment: All the assets are stored in sling:members property. Nodes are also created under the same node, you can also  use a query like this. 
path=/content/dam/collections/k/kXjI0j44sW4pq2mWc9fE/public collections/sling:members
type=nt:unstructured
p.limit=-1

But, it's better to read the property directly as query is again an overhead.

Comment: use `com.day.cq.dam.api.collection.SmartCollection` api instead of sling `ResourceCollection`, it provides a `getQuery` method , also `getResources` is modified to get assets by executing query when applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Storing assets in the collections would be a bad idea since assets can be part of multiple collections. Like in a playlist the assets are only referenced in the collection.

Every collection has a subnode "sling:members". This subnode has a (multi value) property sling:resources that holds references to each asset that is member of this collection.
On top of that, sling:members also has subnodes of type nt:unstructured for each asset with a property sling:resource and again the path to the asset.

[image]

So you can either iterate the property values or the subnodes to get references to the assets and then access them at their original location.

HTH